# How to solve Error: req#logout requires a callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have an error when trying to log out:

```
"Error: req#logout requires a callback function
    at req.logout.req.logOut (C:\FrontEnd\web\2023\Login\node_modules\passport\lib\http\request.js:65:44)
    at C:\FrontEnd\web\2023\Login\app.js:70:8
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\FrontEnd\web\2023\Login\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at next (C:\FrontEnd\web\2023\Login\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\FrontEnd\web\2023\Login\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\FrontEnd\web\2023\Login\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at C:\FrontEnd\web\2023\Login\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
    at Function.process_params (C:\FrontEnd\web\2023\Login\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
    at next (C:\FrontEnd\web\2023\Login\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
    at serveStatic (C:\FrontEnd\web\2023\Login\node_modules\serve-static\index.js:75:16)"
```

This is my code in app.js:

```
const methodOverride = require('method-override')
app.use(methodOverride('_method'))
app.delete('/logout', (req,res) => {
   req.logOut()
   res.redirect('/login')
})
```

And also in index.ejs I have:

```
<form action="/logout?_method=DELETE" method="POST">
   <button type="submit">Log out</button>
</form>
```

Also I've already tried to use the code below in app.js instead:

```
app.post('/logout', function(req, res, next) {
   req.logout(function(err) {
     if (err) { return next(err); }
     res.redirect('/');
   });
});
```

In this case I have the following error:

Cannot DELETE /logout

Why is this happening and how can I solve this issue?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: For your second attempt what happens if you remove `_method=DELETE` from the action?

Answer (score 0):

You are sending a POST request to the server rather than a DELETE request. You can try with changing your index file to send a DELETE request like this:

```
 <form action="/logout" method="POST">
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
  <button type="submit">Log out</button>
 </form>
```